# ARM STM32 toolchain using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, arm, stm32, toolchain

I just got myself an Olimex STM32 E407 and the USB TINY-H Debugging Adapter and would like to know if there is any way setting up a toolchain in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 NOT using VisualGDB, as I do not really want to pay for another tool.

I have searched many forums and pages, but most either consider Linux (which atm is a problem with my computer due to the annoying UEFI BIOS) or need VisualGDB. And to be honest, I really like Visual Studio.

I would not mind doing command line action and if absolutely necessary also might consider installing MinGW.

Thanks a lot for help,
G.

Comment: Other compromise options: Keil's µVision is quite Visual Studio-y and the MDK-Lite version looks to be free. If it comes to Linux, VirtualBox is my favourite way of solving the hardware issues.

Comment: After trying hard and without success to get the jtag adpater running under win 8 I really consider trying to disable uefi and installing fedora. Seems to be way easier. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: For all potentially interested users: Win 8 is problematic, the driver for a JTag/USB TINY H adapter does not even work correctly. Finally, I decided to go for good old emacs in Win7 installing the original STM tool chain and MinGW plus Make. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Ok, what is the motivation for downvoting this question? Gosh, some people here really have problems. Go and get yourself some green tea.

Answer (score -1):

I use VisualGDB and really like it. Since you want a free option, be sure to take a look at http://www.wingdb.com/ .

**Edit**
VisualGDB is not free as on May 2015 and it has a trial of 30 days.

Comment: WinGDB isn't free either (it's $89 for one copy).